# How to connect two computers on the same network?

Tags: networking, router

I have two computers which are connected through wireless connection to the same router.
I want one of them to host a server and the other one to be a client. How can I establish such connection between the two?

Comment: they are already connected on the same network more than likely. If they use the same router/switch (dhcp), otherwise the only thing stopping them from talking to each other are firewalls.

Comment: They are on the same network so it's really up to you what server and client you want to run. Web server, file server, game server or whatever, without telling us what you want to achieve then all we can say is that the computers are there and ready so go for it.

Answer (score 1):

The terms host and client are relative to the services provided, not the connection. So if you are referring to a web host, one machine needs to provide web services (Apache, IIS, etc ) and the other would use web consuming software like a browser.
Most services can be hosted on both machines like files sharing, and the machine requesting the resource would be the client.